How do I replicate the halftone/almost twillish texture in adobe suite, of this drawing by George Wylesol?
I am trying to replicate the fire extinguisher in the bottom left. I am curious about how to generally replicate the look of this image, but also specifically how the texture creates the twill-esque pattern on panel with the extinguisher.
I have made my own version of the extinguisher in illustrator and am assuming I will need to go to photoshop to achieve this look.
Grateful for any guidance.


Take a look at this post: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/104553/looking-to-replicate-a-comic-coloring-of-early-90snot-just-using-the-half-tone/104559#104559

It's possible to add a colour halftone effect right inside Illustrator. No need to do it in Photoshop.
What I would do is prepare the artwork so that the solid black lines are separate objects from the colour fills. Black lines on top (with no fill obviously) and the colour fills underneath these.
Group all the colour fill objects, and apply the colour halftone effect to this group only, and not to the black lines. This will result in a much sharper look.
In the colour halftone filter, tweak the screen angle settings for each channel (as shown below).


Thank you! I was using the halftone effect but couldn't get the angles to replicate the look as you have done here. Really appreciate the work and advice!!
